# Error in projecting to Lambert Conformal Conic with One Standard Parallel in ArcMap

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, lambert-conformal-conic, prj

I am trying to project a polygon from UTM 46 N to Lambert Conformal Conic (1SP) in ArcMap using the following *.proj* file.

```
PROJCS["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_1SP",
      GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
      DATUM["D_WGS_1984",
      SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],
      PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
      UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
      PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic"],
      PARAMETER["false_easting",2743186.0],
      PARAMETER["false_northing",914395.0],
      PARAMETER["central_meridian",90.0],
      PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9988],
      PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",26.0],
      UNIT["Meter",1.0],
      AUTHORITY["Esri",9801]]
```

However, the output coordinate system is not recognized by the program and the following error shows up

> Error: Invalid extent for output coordinate system

I am unable to understand what is actually wrong with my *.prj* file. The definition of the projection is as follows:

> Name: LCC1 (Lambert Conformal Conic - One Standard Parallel)
>
> Spheroid: Everest Central
>
> Meridian: 90 E of Greenwich
>
> Latitude of Origin: 26 (Standard Parallel)
> False Northing: 914,395 meters
>
> False Easting: 2,743,186
>
> Scale Factor: 0.9988

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding `["standard_parallel",26.0]` to the *.proj* file. The definition includes both Latitude of Origin and Standard Parallel as 26 degree. I thought defining only one would work. But it seems both of the parameters were necessary for the Lambert Conformal Conic projection.